# PyQt and Netgraph Editable Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, interactive, netgraph

I already have an PyQt application working along with Netgraph.

I am able to move vertex and edges, given the following code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from netgraph import InteractiveGraph

import networkx as nx


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        graph = nx.house_x_graph()
        self.plot_instance = InteractiveGraph(graph, ax=self.ax)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Netgraph EditableGraph allows to add or remove vertex and edges, for example. However, in the previous code, if changed from `InteractiveGraph` to `EditableGraph`, nothing is changed.

If you run the following example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from netgraph import EditableGraph

g = nx.house_x_graph()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

plot_instance = EditableGraph(g)

plt.show()
```

Click on every vertex or edge, and then press the delete button, it will be erased.

I want this same behavior inside a PyQt window. I am not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help opening an [issue at netgraph repo](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues/34) and I ended up with the following algorithm:

```py
import sys
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore # <- additional import
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from netgraph import EditableGraph


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.graph = EditableGraph([(0, 1)], ax=self.ax)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        # ----------------------------------------
        # Enable key_press_event events:
        # https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/707/#issuecomment-4181799
        self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.canvas.setFocus()
        # ----------------------------------------

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```